# How to slide one object on another, keeping curvature?

Tags: animation, transforms

I want to make a character that has no actual face but just a pair of goggles that will slide around on his front to show in what direction he is looking. He is round like a cylinder but its not perfectly round. How can I make the goggles stick to him, but keep the curvature?

Comment: you could create a plane, give your glasses a Surface Deform modifier with this plane as target, and give this plane a Shrinkwrap modifier with the face as target, then parent the plane to a bone to make it move.

Comment: thanks so much for the answer, i'm gonna try that, but i won't be able to reply for a while, so i can't tell you if it worked or not. thanks anyway tho :)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would probably create a curve that matches the curve of the character, then use a curve modifier on the glasses.

[image]

If you don't want the goggles to distort, then you could parent the goggles to the path then you can move along the path by changing the frame (left/right arrows on your keyboard). That doesn't work if you are also animating the character though.

[image]

Comment: thanks so much for the answer, i'm gonna try that as well as the answer that "moonboots" gave me, but i won't be able to reply for a while, so i can't tell you if it worked or not. thanks anyway tho :)